# i need to iterate data from string of List and add into another string of list from "MemberOf "Parameter from following JSON

Tags: java, json, spring

i need to iterate data from string of List and add into another string of list from this following JSON.

```
  {
    "userID":"navin",
    "userType":"H",
    "ln":"khus",
    "givenName":"navin Khush",
    "title":"",
    "info":"DD JFKSO",
    "memberOf":[
    "CN=EPWV_ADJSJ,OU=Groups,OU=PA,ou=EPWV,DC=emea",
    "CN=EPWV_PPA_rp,OU=Groups,OU=PA,ou=EPWV,DC=ssf2",
    "CN=EPWV_PPA_rp,OU=Groups,OU=PA,ou=EPWV,DC=ssf3",
    "CN=EPWV_PPA_rp,OU=Groups,OU=PA,ou=EPWV,DC=ssf4"
    ]

    }
```

for above requirement i have created following Logic.

private List memberOf;
private List member;

```
ListIterator<String> iterator = memberOf.listIterator();
{
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String s = iterator.next();
    if(s=="CN") {
        member.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

s is not going to == "CN". s will .contains() "CN". The Java == comparator is checking that the object on the left side references the same point in memory as the object on the right side. Following your example data above your comparison would look like this: "CN=EPWV_ADJSJ" == "CN".

If you want to check that the strings are equal you'd want to use "CN=EPWV_ADJSJ".equals(s) (placing the string first prevents a null pointer exception should s be null). This will only return true if they're exactly equal, however.

More than likely what you're after is:

```
if(s.contains("CN"){
  member.add(s)
}
```

As a side-note, you can also make use of .startsWith("CN") instead of .contains("CN"). The difference would be: "ACN" would not match with startsWith(),  but it would match .contains().